# Python Split usage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime

I'm cocking this up and it should be really simple but the value of sortdate is none (note im only doing this because converting a string to a date in Python is a bugger).

```
DateToPass = str(self.request.get('startdate'))
mybreak.startdate = DateToPass
faf = DateToPass.split('-')
sortdate = str(faf[2] + faf[1] + faf[0])
```

That should work? but its just being stored as null though the datetopass is being stored fine.

Comment: You're not actually setting it on the model (did you mean mybreak.sortdate = ...?). Is that intentional? Also, using a DateTimeProperty would make this much simpler.

Comment: you'll need to tell us what the string you're trying to split looks like - some examples.

Comment: sorry thats a "clip" of the code for that class. mybreak is the model (assigned earlier mybreak = MyBreak() ). The string being passed is 21-07-2010; I'm assigning various other bits of text which works fine and is being stored when i push the data; mybreak.put() the 'converted' date is being stored as null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input date is in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD' then the code you have shold work fine. There are a few extraneous str() calls, and yeah, it'd be more proper to use strptime, but nothing that should break.

For example, this works:

```
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Apr 15 2008, 11:28:25)
[GCC 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> startdate = '2002-04-20'
>>> splitdate = startdate.split('-')
>>> type(splitdate[0])
<type 'str'>
>>> splitdate[2]+splitdate[1]+splitdate[0]
'20042002'
```

So the two places I'd look are:

1. What is the format you get from self.request.get('startdate') and store in DateToPass?
2. You haven't shown us the code where you *store* sortdate. Is it broken?

Comment: The store is working fine for storing the date as string, but it was storing the reconstituted date (as in the code chunk) as null; all the other data in the model was fine. Hence I assumed split worked differently or I was going totally wrong :o) ... Yours answers the question as it was asked (regarding splits) which is handy to understand as I'll be using it a lot. Thanks, now I can go back to the C++ ;o)
                                                                    
>> As below I missed the f#@ing model off the start of the string argh

Answer (score 4):

It would be helpful to see what `self.request.get('startdate')` looked like.  Is it ISO (`YYYY-MM-DD`)?  If so I'll show an example using `datetime`.  There's no need for splits because of `datetime.datetime.strptime`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date_to_pass = '2010-05-07'
>>> sortdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_to_pass, '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> sortdate
datetime.datetime(2010, 5, 7, 0, 0)
```

Datetime objects are sortable, so there's no need to convert to a string.  Unless I'm missing the point of your question.

Comment: Sorry time delay long drive home. 
The date is being entered in UK format (dd-mm-YY) 21-05-2010; I should probably test it locally a bit now I'm not working from a remote desktop but basically all routes either lead to an error regarding the string when I used '%d-%m-%Y' which started me off on the wild goose chase. I expect I'll try this code now and itll work ;o) heres hoping

Comment: Glad to help.  In that case your format string would be `'%d-%m-%y'` (small y for year, big Y for century + year).

Comment: Ta, It was a 'hard of thinking' moment, so much so I mooched around http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html then rewrote the whole app. :o) Pythons not all bad, just niggly.

Answer (score 1):

If the *real* issue is converting a string to a time, as you have indicated, then have you looked into [`time.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime)?

Comment: Its to datetype i was looking to achieve originally; and yep ive been down that rabbit hole; I think adding this extra column for sorting based on YYmmdd will suffice as this is a rush job.